# Spring Integration FTP - InboundChannelAdapter Stopped working with new FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration-ftp

I've been using Spring-Integration 4.1.6 to connect to an old FTP server for several years now.   The FTP server was recently replaced with a newer version (the new server is Globalscape EFT Enterprise) and immediately my int-ftp inbound-channel-adapters stopped finding files.  I monitor several accounts and they all stopped working at the same time.

Here is the configuration of one:

```
<beans:bean id="ftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <beans:property name="host" value="${ftp.host}" />
    <beans:property name="port" value="${ftp.port}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${ftp.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${ftp.password}" />
    <beans:property name="clientMode" value="2" />
    <beans:property name="fileType" value="2" />
    <beans:property name="bufferSize" value="5000000" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="cachingSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ftpSessionFactory" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="1" />
    <beans:property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="60000" />
</beans:bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundChannelAdapter" channel="ftpChannelIn" session-factory="cachingSessionFactory" auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="true" remote-directory="dev" local-directory="C:/temp" auto-startup="true">
    <poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" receive-timeout="10000" cron="0 0/2 * * * *" >
        <transactional/>
    </poller>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

and when I debug the adapter, I see this statement:

```
[org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer] cannot copy, not a file: dev/dev
```

But there is no folder named dev underneath dev, only a single .csv file.

The structure is /path/to/user/dev/file.csv and the FTP server is configured to show the entire path to the user when they do a PWD.

And I am sure that when the login happens, they are placed in the /path/to/user folder.

I stood up another FTP server on my local environment, and it worked fine.

Have there been problems with certain non-standard FTP servers causing issues like this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the latest version of GlobalScape EFT (8.0.2.x) has incorrectly implemented the LIST command.  When a LIST some/directory is performed for monitoring, they were returning the details of the directory itself and not the contents of the directory.  This was a change in behavior from their 7.x version.

It would have been nice if I could have configured the Spring Integration FTP library do a CWD and then LIST of the current folder.  Or have it use NLST.  However, as this was just a bug on a FTP server, it is completely understandable why that is not an option.